# Self developed HTTP server

Tags: http

I developed my own HTTP server under Windows\Linux.
The problem: after entering the URL in Chrome, I have to refresh 2 or 3 times until the page is loaded.

If I'm using Microsoft HTTP server or Apache (for Linux) it works always on the first refresh.

Is there a specification that I should implement?
According to few links I found, there is no way to set timeout in Chrome.

Comment: for starters: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616 https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7540 https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2818 probably some more ...

Comment: RFC2616 is obsolete.  Use https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230 and onwards for HTTP/1.1